# How to restore the thermostat previous set temperature?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch, nest-device-access

I wrote this script for a Nest thermostat. It has to store the current set heating temperature (`settemp`), heat for 6 seconds at 20°C then heat again to the previous set temperature (`settemp` that was defined prior to the heating value change).

This is (part of) my code:

```
try {

// url fetch to call api
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + endpoint, params);
const responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
const responseBody = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

// log responses
console.log("Response code: " + responseCode);
console.log(responseBody);

// get devices
const devices = responseBody['devices'];
//console.log(devices);

devices.forEach(device => {
  
  if (outside_temp < 15) 

{

var tempCelcius = device\['traits'\]\['sdm.devices.traits.Temperature'\]\    ['ambientTemperatureCelsius'\].toFixed(1);
//Logger.log('MODE' + JSON.stringify(data));
//if (sdm.devices.commands.ThermostatMode.SetMode == OFF) return
const settemp = device\['traits'\]\['sdm.devices.traits.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint'\]\    ['heatCelsius'\].toFixed(1);
Logger.log('settemp: ' + settemp);

// set the endpoint

const endpoint1 = '/enterprises/'  + PROJECT_ID + '/devices/' + DOWNSTAIRS_THERMOSTAT + ':executeCommand';

const data =
{
'command' : 'sdm.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint.SetHeat',
'params' : {
'heatCelsius': 12,
}
}

const options = {
'headers': headers,
'method': 'post',
'payload': JSON.stringify(data),
'muteHttpExceptions': true

}
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));

try {
// try calling API
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + endpoint1, options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
catch(e) {
console.log('Error: ' + e);
}
Utilities.sleep(6000);
try {
// try calling API
const data1 =
{
'command' : 'sdm.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint.SetHeat',
'params' : {
'heatCelsius': settemp,
}
}

const options1 = {
'headers': headers,
'method': 'post',
'payload': JSON.stringify(data1),
'muteHttpExceptions': true
}
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data1));
Logger.log('settemp: ' + settemp);
const response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + endpoint1, options1);
Logger.log(response1.getContentText());
}
catch(e) {
console.log('Error: ' + e);
}

}
}
)}
catch(e) {
console.log('Error: ' + e);
}
```

`Logger.log(settemp)` always displays the right value in the console, but I get that error every time:

`{ "error": { "code": 500, "message": "Internal error encountered.", "status": "INTERNAL" } }`

May it be caused by a conflict between `settemp` and `'command' : 'sdm.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint.SetHeat'`?

Would you know how to solve that error please? I tried many many things, including moving `const data1` and `const options1` in different places, but nothing worked.

A huge thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer!

The problem came from the decimals

```
const settemp = device['traits']['sdm.devices.traits.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint']['heatCelsius'].toFixed(1);
```

which I just had to change to

```
const settemp = device['traits']['sdm.devices.traits.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint']['heatCelsius'].toFixed(0);
```